# Trying to compute the average for unsigned long long from a file using bash

Tags: bash, file-io, printing, awk

Trying to compute the average for unsigned long long from a file using bash.

So I have a text file which has unsigned long long in a column (e.g. 18446743829774150033)
and I want to compute the average of the numbers in the file and output it to the file. I tried awk but I think it doesn't work for the unsigned long long.

```
awk '{a+=$1; b++} END{print a/b}' file.txt
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that awk falls back on floating point when the numbers are too large, causing inaccuracies. You can use a use bc instead, which supports arbitrary precision:

```
a=($(cut -f1 file.txt))
echo "($(IFS=+; echo "${a[*]}"))/${#a[@]}" | bc
```

It's a bit magic, but if you just remove the `bc`, you see that it turns a set of numbers like  `1 2 3` into `(1+2+3)/3`, which bc can work on.

If you want decimals, you can set the scale:

```
a=($(cut -f1 file.txt))
echo "scale=4; ($(IFS=+; echo "${a[*]}"))/${#a[@]}" | bc
```

Comment: NICE! will this restore into the same file?

Comment: It does not modify the file, if that's what you're asking

Comment: How do I make it skip the first line and re output to the end of the same file?

Comment: echo "($(IFS=+; echo "${a[*]}"))/${#a[@]}" | bc >> file.txt works I believe for outputing to the end of the same file. How do I just check to make sure the value being read is a number?

Comment: Yes. And you can use `a=($(cut -f1 file.txt | sed 1d | grep '^[0-9]*$))` to skip the first line and only sum the numbers